# Are all operators really associative?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, momentum, commutator

Operators are associative as seen [here](http://vergil.chemistry.gatech.edu/notes/quantrev/node13.html).

But when we try to calculate $[\hat{x}, \hat{p}]$ for example, we use a test function and apply $\hat{p}$ to both $\hat{x}$ and the function, instead of associating $\hat{p}$ with $\hat{x}$ and be done with it (obviously the result would be incorrect).

Edit to elaborate my question:

$[\hat{x}, \hat{p}] f =  \hat{x}\hat{p}f - (\hat{p} \hat{x}) f = \hbar/i \bigg(\hat{x} (\partial f/\partial x) - (\partial x/\partial x)f\bigg) = \hbar/i \bigg(\hat{x} \ \partial /\partial x - 1) f\bigg)$

Why can't we do what we did on the second term? Associate the operators before applying them on the test functions?

Comment: As a general trend, mathematicians focus on associative algebras.  Non-associative algebras are excruciating and great efforts are taken to avoid them.

Comment: Are you joking, right? Lie algebras are all over the place in physics!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Operators act on elements of the Hilbert space, not other operators.  $\hat p$ and $\hat x$ are defined by how they act on states, e.g.

$$\hat p: f(x) \mapsto -if'(x)$$
$$\hat x: f(x) \mapsto x\cdot f(x)$$

There is no sense in which $\hat p$ can act on $\hat x$, or vice versa.  We can, however, *compose* operators (also called *multiplying* them, by overloading the term "multiply") by applying them one after another:

$$(\hat p \circ \hat x): f(x) \mapsto \hat p\big(\hat x(f(x))\big) = \hat p\big(x f(x)\big) = -i\big[x f(x)\big]'$$
$$(\hat x \circ \hat p): f(x) \mapsto \hat x\big(\hat p(f(x))\big) = \hat x\big(-if'(x)\big) = -ixf'(x)$$

where $\hat p \circ \hat x$ is pronounced "$\hat p$ after $\hat x$".  It is conventional to drop the $\circ$ notation, but this is what appears in the commutation relations.

Comment: I see, but what about operators in matrix form? Do they still belong to Hilbert space if they can act on one another or "multiply" into one operator?

Comment: @DiaaEldinMalek Operators aren't elements of the Hilbert space $\mathcal H$, they live in $End(\mathcal H)$ - the space of endomorphisms on $\mathcal H$ (that is, maps from $\mathcal H$ back to itself).  Given any two endomorphisms, you can "multiply" (or compose) them together to get another endomorphism.  Note - what I've said requires some slight tweaking if the operators can't act on the whole Hilbert space (like $\hat p$ and $\hat x$, in general), but it is true for finite matrix operators.

Answer (score 7):

Suppose we want to evaluate
$$\hat{p} \hat{x} \psi(x).$$
Everything here is perfectly associative, so you can evaluate it two ways,
$$\hat{p} \hat{x} \psi(x) = (\hat{p} \hat{x}) \psi(x) = \hat{p} (\hat{x} \psi(x)).$$
The error you made is that you can't compute $\hat{p} \hat{x}$ like this:
$$\hat{p} \hat{x} = - i\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \hat{x} \neq - i\frac{\partial}{\partial x} x = - i.$$
The issue is that $\hat{x}$ isn't the same thing as $x$. The operator $\hat{x}$ *acts on* wavefunctions $\psi(x)$ by multiplying them by $x$, but that isn't the same thing as saying it is the number $x$. The operator $\hat{p} \hat{x}$ needs to be thought of as doing these two operations in order: multiply wavefunctions by $x$, then apply $- i \partial / \partial x$.

Comment: You could evaluate $(\hat p\hat x)$ through matrix multiplication right?

Comment: Not very convenient though as they are infinite dimensional matrices.

Comment: @Charlie Yeah, but it would be really annoying. The point of the early-undergrad "acting on functions" notation that OP is using is to avoid having to talk about matrix elements or bases, but to do the multiplication you'll have to.

Comment: knzhou & @Manny Ok thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Operators, in general, are associative. Associative means that we can calculate in a different order
$$ABC = (AB)C = A(BC)$$
but it does not mean that we can write the operators in a different order. You are confusing it with commutative. We do not, in general have
$$AB = BA$$

Consider a simple example. If you reflect an image in the $y$-axis (operator $B$), and then rotate the result by $90^\circ$ (operator $A$) then you will get a different result from rotating the image and then reflecting. In matrices this is 
$$AB = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
-1& 0 \\
0 &1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\neq
\begin{pmatrix}
-1& 0 \\
0 &1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
=BA
$$
as you can easily check.

Comment: Oh no, I didn't mean that. I meant when using a test function to evaluate $ \hat{p} (\hat{x} f(x))$, why can't we do $ (\hat{p}\hat{x}) f(x)$?

edit:
That way p is just a derivative with respect to x acting on x, so it's 1.
The commutator would evaluate to $x  {\partial}/{\partial x} - 1$

Comment: I have given an example to show that operators do not in general commute

Answer (score 1):

No, operators are not all associative. Though in regards to your example, linear operators acting on a separable Hilbert space are. It would be interesting if any new formulation of quantum mechanics can make use of non-associative operators. Some people wrote more ideas about that and other physical applications in the following post.

[Non-associative operators in Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/67266/non-associative-operators-in-physics)

One of the answers mentioned some work done using deformation quantization as a possible way to work towards that idea (eventually). I wanted to at least mention it since that method is highly related to (a particular) *functional calculus*, which seems more closely related to the spirit of your question and comes up in commutator computations often.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice your answer until now.
This is definitely interesting, I will check it out. Thank you!